# React js: Why I'm unable to create closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I have `isLeap` as a prop which checks if the current year is leap and another prop `currentMonth` which is current month's count. (e.g 1 for Feb)

Console throws `"Unexpected token"` error, when I try to create a function within a function or closure as below

```
  70 |  },
  71 |  daysInMonth : function(d){
> 72 |      var leapCase = function(this.props.isLeap){
     |                           ^
  73 |      }
  74 |  },
  75 |  render : function(){
```

And in render function I'm calling above function via my component's attribute as:

```
<Week key={i} dayCount = {this.daysInMonth(this.props.currentMonth)} />
```

Comment: `Unexpected token this` ?

Comment: with `leapcase` I'm trying to check if February falls under leap year. If so return 29 else return 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a closure you need to wrap the function like this

```
var leapCase = (function(props){

    return function(){
        if (props.isLeap){
            ...
        }
    };    

})(this.props)
```

Comment: Thanks. It was useful!

Answer (score 3):

You tried to initiate a function with an argument `this` which is used to determine by how a function is called. If you want to access this.props in the closure, Try this.

```
  70 |  },
  71 |  daysInMonth : function(){
            var props = this.props
  72 |      var leapCase = function(){
     |         console.log(props.isLeap)
  73 |      }
  74 |  },
  75 |  render : function(){
```

And in render function, call it like

```
<Week key={i} dayCount = {this.daysInMonth.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: @Hacketo Oops, i forgot

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error, you can not use `.` and `this` [in name of function argument](https://jsfiddle.net/z0mwowvh/1/),

```
var leapCase = function(isLeap) {
  // ... 
};

leapCase(this.props.isLeap)
```